# button Addnew and save c#

Tags: c#

I am creating a software to store data which connect to Access Database, the problem is about  **AddNew** button I have to click AddNew buttom and after filling I have to Click and save ( not a good idea on my code) what I want is when I click AddNew button , It's create news list and after filling the form just click AddNew again it automatic save to database. 
here is my code:

```
 private void buttonAddNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.table1BindingSource.AddNew();
        }
```

[Here the image][1]
i.stack.imgur.com/X5HEO.png

Comment: Why don't you just fill the form and click `New data`? You would need to check if the informations in the form are already in the database and depending on the result, you save it or don't and return an error message.

Comment: There is no need to save records one at a time - the DB providers can store many many inserted and changed records, assuming you are using a DataAdapter.  Failing that, it is very hard to be of assistance without seeing how you are saving data.  Also, those inout text controls are redundant too - you can perform inserts and edits directly in the grid

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no AddNew button in attachment that is NewData, so be very specific what are you asking about.

Here what i understand that, you want to reuse AddNew Button. If I'm correct then you can do like this.

```
// your button name might be change
If(btnAddNew.text == "AddNew")
{
// access your database and fill form.
btnAddNew.text = "Save";
}
elseIf(btnAddNew.text == "Save")
{
// save your data into database
btnAddNew.text = "AddNew";
}
```

If you don't wish to change your button text then you can add a bool flag like NewEntry =  false. After fetch and fill value in form set it to true and then after save data into table set it to false;